# Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char

Tags: node.js, api, axios, request, backend

I work by a company that make requests on flights company.
I can make my request by Insominia in production and homologation, but, if I try local, I get this error:

```
Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:532:15)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:17) {bytesParsed: 699, code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN', reason: 'Invalid header value char', rawPacket: Buffer(970), config: {…}, …}
```

All my friends can make this request in their Insominia, in local. I only have this problem with this specific request, in this specific site, if I do in any other site, I got what I need. it doesn't make sense to me, and I already tried downgrade my axios version, delete node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json, copy this documents from my friends, delete, clone and npm install all this project from git and nothing happens in this specific request, in this specific site.

What can I do?